# Where can one get songs identified?

Tags: discussion

Since song identification is off topic, where is a good forum for this? I have two pieces that need identifying and I know they are not popular pieces.

Comment: I've already tried SoundHound and Shazam

Comment: Feel free to ask in chat-- just about anything goes there.

Comment: Ok great, will do.